# First Order Logic: Help with the Transformation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

i have to translate this sentence into FOL.Hope to have done the right solution.

"*Paul is a tall guy that has 3 dogs: Pike,Like,Zike. Dogs that have a owner are happy if and only if their owner feeds them. Paul loves his dogs.Everybody feeds those they loves unless the food is over*"

My solution:

1) Guy(Paul) $\land$ Tall(Paul) $\land$ HasDog(Paul,Pike) $\land$ HasDog(Paul,Like) $\land$ HasDog(Paul,Zike)

2) $\forall x$ $\exists y$ [Dog(y)$\land$ HasDog(x,y) $\land$ Feeds(x,y)$\iff$  Happy(y)]

3)Loves(Paul,Pike) $\land$ Loves(Paul,Zike) $\land$ Loves(Paul,Like)

4)$\neg$ Over(Food) $\Rightarrow$ 
  [ $\forall x$ $\exists y$ loves(x,y) $\Rightarrow$ Feeds(x,y) ]

For indicating the predicate "All owners of their own dogs" i used $\forall x$ $\exists y$, because alternatively it would have meant that every person in the domain is the owner of every animal of the domain. Is this right?

Thanks

Comment: A translation question is not well-defined until the available predicates / functions are defined.

Comment: Sorry i forget to specify that i have to use my own vocabulary

Comment: If I were doing this for "real life", I'd change "HasDog(Paul,Pike)" to "Owns(Paul,Pike) /\ IsDog(Pike)" or something. HasDog() combines two predicates in my mind. In your current scheme, HasDog(x,y) -> IsDog(y), so your statement 2) contains a redundant /\

Comment: well, having a deeper look you are right! What's about the others formulae?@barrycarter

Comment: For 2), I think you need "for all x, for all y"; otherwise, you're saying: for each owner, there is one dog who is only happy when fed. That's probably not what you mean.

Comment: For 3), you could do "Owns(Paul,x) /\ IsDog(x) => Love(Paul,x)" or something... says the same thing but looks slightly more clever.

Comment: For 2), so even if i use "for all x and for all y" this would not means that is true for all animal y? I mean, Every x owns every y of the universe, and this is not true right? @barrycarter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66110/discussion-between-barrycarter-and-rollotommasi).

Comment: What's about the last one? Would be better to use Present(food) instead of $\neg$ Over (food) ?